# How to test Math-related units?

Tags: math, tdd

I'm giving TDD a serious try today and have found it really helpful, in line with all the praise it receives.

In my quest for exercises on which to learn both Python and TDD i have started to code SPOJ exercises using the TDD technique and i have arrived at a question:

Given that all of SPOJ's exercises are mostly math applied to programming; How does one test a math procedure as in the TDD Fashion? Sample known-to-be-correct data? Test against a known implementation?

I have found that using the sample data given in the problem itself is valuable but it feels overkill for something you can test so quickly using the console, not to mention the overhead to design your algorithms in a testable fashion (Proxying the stdout and stdin objects is nothing short of too much work for a really small reward), and while it is good because it forces you to think your solutions in testable terms i think i might be trying way too hard on this.

All guidance is welcome

Comment: "Sample known-to-be-correct data?" Yes. "Test against a known implementation?" Yes.

Comment: "Proxying the stdout and stdin objects" - you shouldn't need to do that.  Separate your code into the component dealing with IO (parsing and formatting), and the core algorithm.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth In that regard, i came up with this: http://pastebin.com/vPZKeJEX

Answer (score 1):

test all edge cases. Your program is most likely to fail when the input is special for some reason: negative, or zero values, very large values, inputs in reverse order, empty inputs. You might also want some destructive tests to see how large the inputs can be before things break or grind to a halt.

[Sphere online Judge](http://www.spoj.com/) may not be the best fit of TDD. For one the input data might be better behaved than what a real person might put in. Secondly there is a code size limit on some problems. An extensive test-suite might put you over that limit.

Comment: The tests are for my personal use only, SPOJ submissions would be just the code that matters to the problem only.

Comment: Awesome suggestions by the way, thanks. Can't mark as answer though as this is mostly an open question - surprised it hasn't been flagged as one

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Uncle Bob's "[Transformation Priority Premise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_Priority_Premise)." It offers some guidance on how to pick a sequence of tests to test drive an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Use sample inputs for which you know the results (outputs). Use equivalence partitioning to identify a suitable set of test cases. With maths code you might find that you can not implement as incrementally as for other code: you might need several test cases for each incremental improvement. By that I mean that non maths code can typically be thought of as having a set of "features" and you can implement one feature at a time, but maths code is not much like that.

Comment: Can i have some explanation over the "incremental improvement" please?